# greasemonkey script to find all url of a domain in a page and change it

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want a greasemonkey script which will scan each page for url of a domain and add a parameter to it

For example, if I visit a page it will scan all URLs with domain example.com and replace `example.com/abc` to `example.com/abc/xyz` 
and if I am directly on `example.com/abc` it will add `/xyz` after it.
The code below can do what I want but only when I am on `example.com`

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name Bypass uppit adds
// @include http://*example.com/*
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript== 
var url=window.location.pathname;
var url1=url+"xyz";
window.location.replace(url1);
```

what i want is when i am refereed to any page of this domain the url i will click should be the final one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name Bypass uppit adds
// @include *
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==
if(window.location.pathname.match(example.com)) {
    var url1=url+"/xyz";
    window.location.replace(url1);
}
else {
    var allLinks, thisLink;
    allLinks = document.evaluate(
        '//a[@href]',
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
        null);
    for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.snapshotLength; i++) {
        thisLink = allLinks.snapshotItem(i);
        if(thisLink.match(http://example.com))
            thisLink+="xyz";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
 var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

then you can loop over these using:

```
links[i] = url;
```